# How to hold an array of any number of characters in a struct

Tags: c, pointers

Having a lot of trouble understanding pointers and how to use them with functions. Trying to write a function that takes an array of characters of any size and holds it in a struct.This is what I have tried but getting seg error.

```
#define LENGTH 50

typedef struct{
    char *pass;
    int length;
}pass_t;

void createNewPassword(pass_t *password);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pass_t *password=NULL;

    createNewPassword(password);
    printf("%d",password->length);
}


void
createNewPassword(pass_t *password){
    char c;
    int i, n=LENGTH;

    if (!(password->pass=malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char)))) {
        printf("Out of memory, exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter a new password: ");
    while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
        if (i>=n){
            n *= 2;
            if (!(password->pass=realloc(password->pass, 
            (n+1)*sizeof(char)))) {
                printf("Out of memory, exiting.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        password->pass[i++]=c;
    }
    password->pass[i+1]='\0';
    password->length=i;
}
```

Comment: `password` is `NULL`, but `createNewPassword` does not allocate memory for it before accessing `pass`.

Comment: also `int i` --> `int i=0`, `password->pass[i+1]='\0';` --> `password->pass[i]='\0';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, inside your `createNewPassword()` function, the parameter `password` is NULL. You're essentially dereferencing a NULL pointer. it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to `password` before using it.

That said, you're passing `password` directly to `createNewPassword()`. You cannot allocate memory to `password` inside that function and expect that to be reflected to `main()`, as `C` uses pass-by-value.  Either allocate memory from `main()` itself, or pass a pointer to `password`, if you want to allocate memory from `createNewPassword()`.

Then again, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` in `C`, you don't need to add that as a multiplier for getting the size. It's redundant.

Comment: And once that's fixed, the `printf("%d",password->length);` call in `main()` will fail for the same reason - the passed-in variable won't (can't) be modified by the function, and will still be `NULL` on return.